# Java object add / update / remove algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm which will update a list of Java objects I have regularly in the most efficient and effective manner.  The algorithm needs to...

Current set

```
A, B, C
```

Reload instruction called and returns a new set from the DB

```
A, C, D
```

(ie. `A` & `C` should be updated(if necessary), `B` needs to be removed & `D` is new and should be created)

Obviously I could kill all the objects and just recreate all of them each time but I want to avoid killing any objects which are not changing (ie. if `A` & `C` have not changed in the DB then the current Java `A` & `C` objects should be left alone to continue in their current guise).

I need to have a good algorithm which will do these various checks then add/update/remove as necessary.  The logic for my situation should be able to carry over from a simple `ArrayList<String>` example I'd think as obviously my `A`/`B`/`C` objects are much more complex.

Comment: Are you using some caching/persistence layer between your DB and your Java code?

Comment: "Obviously I could kill all the objects and just recreate all of them each time" <-- well, why don't you do just that? You say yourself that you read from your DB each time, there is no reason to bother yourself.

Comment: Sorry "fge" but I cannot dump the object as there are certain ongoing statistical calculations being generated the longer the object remains alive for. Deleting and recreating will mean the unnecessary loss of these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `HashMap` with database ID as keys and full objects as values. You'll iterate over the result set and, by an O(1) operation, find out whether the item is already there. You can then add and update as appropriate. As you proceed, build a temporary `HashSet` of the database keys of all fetched entries. Then do a final set difference to find the items to delete from the runtime copy.

Comment: Thanks Marko.  I am now looping through the new DB result set, adding/updating each along the way.  While doing this, logging each add/update record into a hashmap.  After the result set loop is complete then loop through all my active objects and compare each in turn against my temporary hashmap.  Those that are in the map, ignore as they were added/updated and those that aren't in the map need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 lists one for BusinessLayer and other for UI layer and mark the object accordingly for create/update/delete.
Once identified this marked list could be forwarded to create queries for DB accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should be using a Map for your set.  This will make the lookups more efficient.

You can do a couple of loops to find out what has changed.

```
Map<MyKey, MyType> previous = ..
Map<MyKey, MyType> current = ..

for(Map<MyKey, MyType> entry: current.entrySet()) {
  MyType t = entry.getValue();
  MyType p = previous.get(entry.getKey());
  if (p == null)
      added(t);
  else if (!p.equals(t))
      updated(p, t);
}
for(Map<MyKey, MyType> entry: previous.entrySet()) {
  if(!current.contains(entry.getKey()))
     removed(entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1

Your objects could inherit from a base type, such as :

```
abstract class PersistentObject {
    private boolean persistent;  // true if exists in database
    private boolean modified;    // true if modified
    private boolean deleted;     // true if deleted

    public boolean isPersistent() { return persistent; }
    protected void setPersistent() { persistent = true; }

    public boolean isModified() { return modified; }
    protected void setModified() { modified = true; }

    public boolean isDeleted() { return deleted; }
    protected void setDeleted() { deleted = true; }
}
```

And call / change the state of your object when manipulating them. For example :

```
public void setSomeIntvalue(int value) {
    this.value = value;

    setModified();
}
```

When you commit your changes (iterating over your set), you `DELETE` from the database any deleted object, then remove it from the set. If `isPersistent()` is false, you create a new one, if `isModified()` is true, you `UPDATE` it, otherwise you do nothing.

#### Solution 2

You could have a wrapper to manage your set of objects. Something like :

```
abstract class AbstractEntitySet<E> {
    private HashSet<E> createdSet = new HashSet<E>();
    private HashSet<E> modifiedSet = new HashSet<E>();
    private HashSet<E> deletedSet = new HashSet<E>();

    public void add(E e) {
        add(e, false);
    }

    public void add(E e, boolean modified) {
        if (modified) {
            createdSet.remove(e);
            modifiedSet.add(e);
            deletedSet.remove(e);
        } else {
            createdSet.add(e);
            modifiedSet.remove(e);
            deletedSet.remove(e);
        }
    }

    public void remove(E e) {
        createdSet.remove(e);
        modifiedSet.remove(e);
        deletedSet.add(e);
    }

    public void applyChanges() {
        for (E e : createdSet) {
            createEntity(e);
        }
        createdSet.clear();

        for (E e : modifiedSet) {
            updateEntity(e);
        }
        modifiedSet.clear();

        for (E e : deletedSet) {
            deleteEntity(e);
        }
        deletedSet.clear();
    }

    protected abstract void createEntity(E e);
    protected abstract void updateEntity(E e);
    protected abstract void deleteEntity(E e);
}
```

You could even bind this set directly to your objects :

```
abstract class BaseEntity<E> {
    private AbstractEntitySet<E> connectedSet;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E bindTo(AbstractEntitySet<E> set) {
        connectedSet = set;
        return (E) this;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setCreated() { connectedSet.add((E) this, false); }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setModified() { connectedSet.add((E) this, true); }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setDeleted() { connectedSet.remove((E) this); }
}
```

Where you would declare your objects (for example) :

```
class SomeObject extends BaseEntity<SomeObject> { 
    public void setSomeThing(...) {
        ...
        setModified();
    }
}
```

and create new instances like

```
AbstractEntitySet<SomeObject> entitySet = ...;
...
SomeObject obj = new SomeObject().bindTo(entitySet);
```

Then update your objects, and apply all changes like

```
obj.setSomeThing(...);
...
entitySet.applyChanges();
```

#### Solution 3

You could also use an existing persistence layer, such as [Hibernate](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html), or [JPA](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html) in your application.